# Getting component from which text was selected

Tags: combobox

I have multiple combo boxes in my GUI; when an option is selected it is displayed on a text area. Using the getSelectedText method i can get the text but is there a way to get the exact component that text was entered from?

Comment: You need some more details about what you're doing. Your existing code would be useful.

Comment: Be specific. It would be useful to describe what language and framework you are using. Add the language and framework as tags to help others find your question.